# Centering the h3 tag in the code HTML

Tags: html, css

How do I center the `h3` tag in the in my code? (center of page/column)

```
<fieldset>
<legend><h3>Customize Your Search</h3></legend>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="amd" name="interest" value="amd" checked>
        <label for="amd">AMD</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Centering vertically or horizontally or both?

Answer (score 0):

To align the h3 into the center of the page / column (within the legend) - use CSS to align the legend to center:

```css
legend {text-align:center}
```

```html
<fieldset>
<legend><h3>Customize Your Search</h3></legend>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="amd" name="interest" value="amd" checked>
        <label for="amd">AMD</label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```